# How do I add a .css file depending on div height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to append a css file when my navbar increases in height beyond 54px *(When the text falls to a second line)* and remove it when the height goes below 54px. I've been trying bits of code, but nothing seems to works:

**My failed attempt**

```
var $navscript = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/edt/nav-bar.css" type="text/css"/>';

if ($("#navbar").height() > 54) {
    alert("Activate Code Here");
    $("body").append('navscript');
}
```

Any idea on where i am going wrong?

Comment: Unless you plan to change "absolutely everything", so that the overhead of loading an additional resource could be justified, you should probably just use a single stylesheet, and change an element class dynamically to achieve whatever it may be that you actually to achieve here.

Comment: Could you expand on this @CBroe ? THe solutions below actually work, but it doesn't work responsively. I have to load the page at the specific point where the height changes.

Comment: You'd need to expand on what you actually want to achieve here first ...

Comment: In short, I want to add a CSS script when the height of the #navbar div increases above 54px and remove it when it goes below 54px in realtime, without having to constantly refresh the page.

Comment: Now you are just telling me again what you said before ... What is it that you want to _achieve_ by doing this?

Comment: This is a case of [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) -- you are asking how to attach (and detach?) a stylesheet based on a condition, but you are asking this question because it is what you thought of as a way to solve your _real_ problem which is, I assume, responsive design: "How do I restyle A under circumstance B?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up fixing this in the end, the code I used was a mix of reloading the segment of code upon window resizing and some else statements depending on a DIV's height or width:

```
var $navscript = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/edt/nav-bar.css" type="text/css" data-dynamic />';

var changeSize = 0;
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(".links").height() > 16) {
        if ($('link[data-dynamic]').length === 0) {
            changeSize = window.outerWidth;
            $("head").append($navscript);
        }
    }
    else {
    }

if (changeSize < window.outerWidth) {
    $('link[data-dynamic]').remove()
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

```
$("body").append('navscript');
```

With this, you are appending the String `navscript` to your `body`, maybe you should try appending the variable `$navscript` to the head.

```
var $navscript = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/edt/nav-bar.css" 
type="text/css"/>';

if ($("#navbar").height() > 54) {
    alert("Activate Code Here");
    $("head").append($navscript);
}
```

Though, keep in mind, that adding content dynamically is generally considered a bad practice. Maybe move all of your CSS in one file and append classes to the objects that should be changed by this.

Comment: This works, but I had to load the page at the specific point where the height increases. It doesn't responsively react to the height changes in real-time, any reason why?

Comment: What page did you have to load? Do you mean the CSS-File?

Comment: The HTML page itself. I even added alerts to see if it springs the alert every time the height changes, but it seems to only run the JS code once.

Comment: If you want the code to run multiple times, you should use a while loop, though this would add a lot of those links to your header every second

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but could you give me an example of this?

Comment: I would rather not, but for the reason that you should never, under any circumstances, put this on the web. Like me, others have pointed out that you should just add Classes to the HTML-elements that you want to be effected by the CSS. I can show you how that's done in a chatroom here, if you want to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146691/discussion-between-luca-kiebel-and-charlie-mcshane).

Comment: I see, basically I was requested to activate the "bootstrap mobile nav" the moment the desktop navbar links break into a second line responsively. If this is not safe, then perhaps a example is not needed. Thank you though!

Comment: @CharlieMcShane said: _"It doesn't responsively react to the height changes in real-time"_ ... if you want responsive design you most definitely _don't_ want to continually add/unload a whole stylesheet as changes occur.  You want to look at [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and/or toggle classes on elements as **CBroe** suggests in a comment on your question.  The styles that change based on the toggled classes or the media queries stay as part of your main stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't recommend doing this as it is pretty much bloating the DOM with a lot of link tags (especially if you'll do this when device dimensions changes) and it is overall bad practice.

What I advice you to do is instead using [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to detect device width and height and then apply CSS properties according to that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work:

```
if ($("#navbar").height() > 54) {
   alert("Activate Code Here");
   $("body").append($navscript);
}
```

But seems like you want change navbar style depend on height. In this case you should add event listener (for event which cause height increasing) and place your code there. My opinion that better include your css file in DOM and operate with some css-classes. For example:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   var $navbar = $("#navbar");
   if ($navbar.height() > 54) {
      $navbar.toggleClass('class');
   }
});
```

Comment: This works, but I had to load the page at the specific point where the height increases. It doesn't responsively react to the height changes in real-time, any reason why?

Comment: @Charlie McShane You said "when my navbar increases". Is this happen on resize of window? Which event cause  navbar height increase?

Answer (score 0):

To attach a secondary CSS file only at certain screen sizes, you can put media query rules on the `<link>` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 500px)" href="smallscreens.css" />
```

It's rarely necessary to do this however; most often it's simpler to include whatever @media rules you need inside a single CSS file:

```
/* default rules here */
.foo {font-size: 1000px}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    /* rules for small screens go here */
    .foo {font-size: 10px}
}
```

You can set any number of size breakpoints, using max-width, min-width, or any combination of many other conditions, within the same CSS file.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

(This doesn't exactly meet your requirement of attaching/detaching the css based on the height of a specific div, but I'm guessing that the change in your navbar height is actually due to a change in screen size, and you've dug yourself into an XY problem trying to solve this the hard way.)